# How to make jQuery Mobile only affect one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html

In the website that I am creating I use jQuery Mobile, which granted I don't know much about, and I'm having a big problem. In my website I only link to jQuery Mobile on one page, and I only want to use jQuery Mobile on one page (I don't know if that is possible, but that is what I want to do).

I have four main pages on my website: Homepage.php, SalesForms.php, Reports.php, and Login.php. I only want to use jQuery Mobile on the Reports.php page (I'm using it for its transitions to create a nice looking html form process).

Whenever I go to the Reports.php page it uses jQuery Mobile and jQuery and the jQuery Mobile CSS, which is good. But when I leave the Reports.php page and go to other pages, jQuery Mobile and its CSS is still being used, even when it isn't linked to on those page and when I don't want it to be used.

For example, when I visit Homepage.php it isn't using jQuery Mobile or its CSS, then I visit Reports.php which does use jQuery Mobile and its CSS, and then I visit Homepage.php again and it is still using jQuery Mobile and its CSS. This is a problem for me because jQuery Mobile's CSS is interfering with my CSS on pages other than the Reports.php page, which is the only page it is linked to on.

I want to know if and how I can make jQuery Mobile only be used on the Reports.php page so that if I go to another page after visiting the Reports.php page it doesn't use jQuery Mobile.

Here is my code where I link to jQuery Mobile (I only link to jQuery Mobile in my Reports.php page):

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jQuery.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Main.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

jQuery.css is just a modified version of jQuery's CSS so that it doesn't interfere with my CSS and Main.css is my CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're not using mod_rewrite and your file reports.php is visible on the url.

Based on your comment: This is the output for $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]:

```
string(47) "/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php"
```

So, we're going to use stripos() to check if the user is requesting a page, that has "reports.php" in it! We are using the case insensitive function instead of strpos(), you can find more info at ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php )

You can use the following condition / logic:

```
<?php if ( stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "reports.php") ) : ?>

    <!-- add the html specific to the REPORTS.PHP -->


<?php else: ?>

    <!-- add the html specific to NON REPORTS.PHP Pages -->

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Remember, everything else GOES OUTSIDE THE PHP IF CLAUSE --->
```

The solution for your problem is:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jQuery.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Main.css">
    <?php if ( stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "reports.php") ) : ?>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <?php else: ?>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not using mod_rewrite but this didn't work. I was just supposed to put it where I put my links to my CSS and jQuery right?

Comment: Yes, it should only show the html wrapped on the php if clause, if "reports.php" is on the REQUEST_URI. What's the url of that page ?

Comment: ok, just changed to stripos() it's case-insensitive. Noticed you're making your requests capitalized maybe. This should definitely work!

Comment: yeh, just try the last amend. It should work. let me know!

Comment: That didn't work either. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Are you sure you're not loading the jquery files elsewhere ?

Comment: can you pastie.org your code ?

Comment: Also, instead of the code I gave you, can you try this one  http://pastie.org/9180333 and tell me if you only see this on reports.php ?

Comment: Here: http://pastie.org/private/4zbkonjbiss3smp67wvfq this is for my Reports.php page

Comment: can you paste the output of http://pastie.org/9180341 ? put it on top of reports.php

Comment: This is it string(47) "/~a7068104/2013-2014/Lab_13/Reports/Reports.php"

Comment: It's working fine here. Do you get a number or false from this ? http://pastie.org/9180356

Comment: Are you saving the file properly with this changes ? it's working fine here

Comment: It returns a number. The goal of this code:
`<?php if ( stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "reports.php") ) : ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jQuery.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Main.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>`
Was to make sure that only Reports.php uses jQuery Mobile right? Because that's what I want to happen.

Comment: Please create a new file elsewhere called reports.php and put this code there http://pastie.org/private/t0iwub5wi6nhnxy4n0j9ea you'll see  that you going to find the html code. Rename reports.php to something else, and you'll see the html will be empty.
If it's returning a number, that's good, it's true. it should return false, if wasn't reports.php. only for true its going to show the wrapped html. that's all!

Comment: Exactly! The goal of the clause is to only show whatever is wrapped inside the php, if you are in that particular page Reports.php!

Comment: Look, it's tested here and works fine. Also, you're getting a number out of the test I asked you to do. So, I believe you're loading those same files from a different php include or something! I'll have to go.

Comment: Alright, but it still isn't working for me.

Comment: sorry, I was wrapping everything because I thought it was specific to reports.php. So, now I only wrapped the jquery.mobile. The Css and other jquery, should load in all pages,  but only jquery mobile on reports.php.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. This code is doing it's job but jQuery Mobile and it's CSS are staying loaded after this code runs.

Comment: Yeh the code works as I tested. If this is true, can you accept the answer so it's useful for other people in the future ? about your other issue, I think that you're probably loading it elsewhere, from an include file or something. Also, do you really need to load the normal jquery version along the mobile version ? I'll change the code a bit for that too