# How to avoid jQuery mobile styles on other sections of the website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to used popup to show signup form. For that purpose I have used jQuery mobile's popup.

So when I added jQuery mobile CSS and JavaScript they have affected the whole page. All the text, menus, links and everything is changed by it.

How I can restrict the jQuery Mobile styles and JavaScript to work on that popup only?

I have completed the whole design so I can't change the styles one by one again.

Here is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

and here is my HTML

```
<a href="#popupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b">Delete page...</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Signup</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to Signup</h3>
    <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to apply data-role="none"

Comment: where i should apply this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766378/jquery-mobile-data-role-none-not-working-sometimes#answer-19785861

Comment: For all the elements which is getting styled. You can simply apply through javascript

Comment: This may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676562/apply-jquery-mobile-only-a-portion-of-page and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691145/how-to-make-jquery-mobile-only-affect-one-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Pattern. Please bring the mobile CSS file before your custom CSS file. Will change it completly.

Cheers!